# XSLT filtering takes away some html tags

Tags: 2011, rtf, xslt

We use default Tridion XSLT for RTF field.
This field should take any html text and save it as is. However, some fields are taken out after XSLT transformation.
For example:

input:

> ```
>   <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="loading no-js" /> <!--<![endif]-->
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.min.css" /> 
>   <div id="loader-wrapper">
>      <div id="loader"></div>
>   </div>
> ```

output:

> ```
>   <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><!--<![endif]-->
>   <div id="loader-wrapper">
>      <div id="loader"/>
>   </div>
> ```

For some reason html and link tags dissapear.
Could someone give advice how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The Tridion RTF XSLT formats HTML to XHTML, therefore updating the empty `<div>` tag to be a self closing tag.

See questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537656/creating-anchor-links-in-rich-text-fields-with-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1 for examples of how to resolve this using an embedded `span` tag

You will need something like

```
<template match="div[(@id = 'loader')]">
    <copy>
        <xhtml:span xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="hidden"> </xhtml:span>
    </copy>
</template>
```

To allow HTML 5 and other non-standard tags you will have to extend TcmXhtml.Config as per

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263064/html5-tags-are-not-working-in-rtf-field-for-tridion-2011

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work for me. I added **new-inline-tags: link** and **new-blocklevel-tags: link** into config file, restart "SDL Tridion Content Manager" COM+ and IIS. But without luck

Comment: looks like **link** is reserved somewhere, because **new-inline-tags: newtag** allows **newtag** to be present in RTF

Answer (score 2):

This is not caused by the XSLT, but rather by Tidy, which is also executed when an RTF is updated. The RTF content is wrapped in a `<body/>` tag before processing, so Tidy will remove anything that doesn't belong in the  body of an html page. In your case, html and link elements don't belong in the body, so they are stripped.

That only leaves the question of why you are using a RTF field for this kind of data. RTF fields are intended for allowing content editors to update content. To use them for technical parts of your html page is probably not a good idea anyway.

Comment: I'd rather use text field than RTF, but client wants to have some quick preview for that html in Tridion. We don't use Tridion in classical way and this field made for importing some static html part with javascript and css into external service.